# Docker: no containers, but network cannot be removed due to active endpoints

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a Jenkins build that among other things launches and shuts down some Docker jobs. However it has started to fail with the error:

```
$ docker-compose -f tests/docker-compose.ci-cypress.yml down --remove-orphans -v
Removing network tests_default
error while removing network: network tests_default id a9d08e07cfb56c3003d68677e93a0e5e705594fcdf112c757bded0cacb5562db has active endpoints
```

So I ran some debug logs prior to the error:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND             CREATED        STATUS                    PORTS     NAMES
efc422450a35   53cb2626a94e   "/bin/sh -c yarn"   11 hours ago   Exited (1) 11 hours ago             heuristic_mcclintock
2d51d2a5e5ca   a092989efdbc   "/bin/sh -c yarn"   14 hours ago   Exited (1) 14 hours ago             musing_ride
```

```
$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND             CREATED        STATUS                    PORTS     NAMES
efc422450a35   53cb2626a94e   "/bin/sh -c yarn"   11 hours ago   Exited (1) 11 hours ago             heuristic_mcclintock
2d51d2a5e5ca   a092989efdbc   "/bin/sh -c yarn"   14 hours ago   Exited (1) 14 hours ago             musing_ride
```

Here you can see the troublesome network `tests_default`:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME            DRIVER    SCOPE
6fb2d7bb7ce8   bridge          bridge    local
24fd6a19da38   host            host      local
dae6a7b6062c   none            null      local
a9d08e07cfb5   tests_default   bridge    local
```

Details:

```
$ docker network inspect tests_default
[
    {
        "Name": "tests_default",
        "Id": "a9d08e07cfb56c3003d68677e93a0e5e705594fcdf112c757bded0cacb5562db",
        "Created": "2021-07-22T12:29:08.752318948+03:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.31.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.31.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "tests",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.28.4"
        }
    }
]
```

When I try to remove the network, I get this error:

```
$ docker network remove tests_default
Error response from daemon: error while removing network: network tests_default id a9d08e07cfb56c3003d68677e93a0e5e705594fcdf112c757bded0cacb5562db has active endpoints
```

And here's the actual action I'm trying to run, which results in the same error as above:

```
$ docker-compose -f tests/docker-compose.ci-cypress.yml down --remove-orphans -v
Removing network tests_default
error while removing network: network tests_default id a9d08e07cfb56c3003d68677e93a0e5e705594fcdf112c757bded0cacb5562db has active endpoints
```

I have also tried `sleep 30` before the above command, but it doesn't help.

I have also found this, but the problem is there is no container to target (nothing is running):

```
docker rm -f <containerId>
docker network disconnect -f tests_default <containerName>
```

And also this:

```
$ docker-compose -f tests/docker-compose.ci-cypress.yml rm
No stopped containers
```

Here's the docker-compose.yml related to the above:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  test_350:
    build: ./cypress
    command: NO_COLOR=1 yarn run cypress --env PLATFORM=X,SERVER_VERSION=${SERVER_VERSION} --reporter junit --reporter-options mochaFile=/tests/portal/reports/cypress-350-[hash].xml,toConsole=true
    ipc: host
    volumes:
      - ../cypress.json:/cypress.json
      - ../tests:/tests
    environment:
      - HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy-350-${SERVER_VERSION}:3080
  test_32:
    build: ./cypress
    command: NO_COLOR=1 yarn run cypress --env PLATFORM=Y,SERVER_VERSION=${SERVER_VERSION} --reporter junit --reporter-options mochaFile=/tests/portal/reports/cypress-32-[hash].xml,toConsole=true
    ipc: host
    volumes:
      - ../cypress.json:/cypress.json
      - ../tests:/tests
    environment:
      - HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy-32-${SERVER_VERSION}:3080
  test_dev:
    build: ./cypress
    command: NO_COLOR=1 yarn run cypress --reporter junit --reporter-options mochaFile=/tests/portal/reports/cypress-32-[hash].xml,toConsole=true
    ipc: host
    volumes:
      - ../cypress.json:/cypress.json
      - ../tests:/tests
    environment:
      - HTTP_PROXY=http://host.docker.internal:3080
```

Which is started in Jenkins with:

```
docker-compose -f tests/docker-compose.ci-cypress.yml build
```

And it is later stopped with the command that has started to error out:

```
docker-compose -f tests/docker-compose.ci-cypress.yml down --remove-orphans -v
```

**So the question is**, how can I remove that "ghost" network `tests_default`? It does not appear to be connected to any active containers (and none are running!), yet Docker still sees active endpoints.

Comment: Does deleting the two stopped containers help?  Do you know off hand how you started them?  I'd suspect if you `docker run --net tests_default ...` a container, and it still exists (even if it's stopped), it could cause this problem.

Comment: I'd start by restarting the docker engine (`systemctl restart docker`). Note that will stop any other running containers, and they'll automatically restart of you have a restart policy set.

Comment: Can't do that in the Jenkins context:
```Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart docker.service;
Failed to restart docker.service: Interactive authentication required.;
See system logs and 'systemctl status docker.service' for details.``` but perhaps it could be tried as admin on the actual instance...

Comment: Removing the "extra" containers didn't help. Still getting the same error, and `docker container ls -a` and `docker ps -a` show no containers.

Comment: The `systemctl` command was for running on the host as root, not from within Jenkins.

Comment: Ooh, now that I look at the network inspection log more carefully, that network was created almost 1 week ago! It must be some leftover from some strange event. Perhaps the docker daemon has some issue, or something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

When analysing the `docker network inspect tests_default` log more carefully, I saw that the network `tests_default` in question had been created about 1 week earlier (I was running the setup on 29th):

```
"Created": "2021-07-22T12:29:08.752318948+03:00",
```

So as suspected by @BMitch it seems to have indeed been a stuck/crashed Docker process, or something similar to that.

In my case, replacing the Jenkins container instance with a new one fixed the network issue, so it appears that there was something stuck in the old instance. Now the standard process could proceed:

```
Removing network tests_default
Network tests_default not found.
Creating network "tests_default" with the default driver
```